# Opening Images as Arrays

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a script that should open an image as a 2D array but I can't seem to make it work. I have tried using the numpy an PIL libraries. I tried this on different computers. The issue is that it opens the image as a 2D array on one computer but opens them ups as objects on a different compute running the same version of python.

The code that should open the image and store it as an array can be seen below:

```
img = np.array(Image.open(imagePath))
```

On one computer I get an array but on another one I get an image object like this:

```
array(<PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=I;16B size=320x240 at 0x2289FA8>, dtype=object)
```

Comment: have you 'pushed' the data using Image.asarray(). I think I had to specify dtype='uint8' sometimes and sometimes 'got away' without doing

Comment: @paddyg How would I use Image.asarray()? Is it the same as np.asarray()?? Also, I did try defining the data type but I kept getting the error. : 
_Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    a = np.array(img, dtype='uint16')
SystemError: error return without exception set_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried the imread function from matplotlib?

```
from matplotlib.image import imread
image = imread(image_path)
```

Returns a numpy array and works fine for me (python 3.4).

Comment: I tried that and it works!! Thanks! I'm still puzzled as to why my method works on one computer but doesn't work on a different one. Do you have any ideas as to why that's the case?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with the PIL.
But if I have to guess, I'd blame different versions of python and/or libraries.